# How does the gradient at (0,0) for for f=x*(y^2+10) point in direction of max increase?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

The gradient of $$f(x,y)=x(y^2+10)$$ is $[10,0]$. How does it point to the direction of fastest increase? By looking at the plot of the graph here we can see that the fastest change at $(0,0)$, would be along the direction of $[1,1]$ or $[1,-1]$ (the direction along the red flap. [image: []

Comment: I think the scale of the $z$-axis is being misleading. Try plotting it on GeoGebra or similar.

Comment: @kipf In any case, I can still imagine a function where df/dx = df/dy  but the max rate of increase is not [1,1].

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: The gradient gives only local information, so what happens far away (the red flaps) is irrelevant here. Zoom in really close to the origin if you want to see why the $x$-direction gives the fastest increase there.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for an addition to Hans Lundmark's comment.

A birds-eye view on the field lines of all gradients gives you a much better intuition in this case.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace, meshgrid

lim = 10
x = linspace(-lim,lim,10)
y = linspace(-lim,lim,10)
X, Y = meshgrid(x,y)  
# Assign vector directions
Xp = Y**2+10
Yp = 2*X*Y
plt.streamplot(X,Y,Xp,Yp, density=1.4, linewidth=None)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```